# Establishing connection with the source database failed. External component has thrown an exception

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-migration-assi

I'm using SSMA to migrate an ACCESS back-end to SQL Server.  The Load and Link (usually) work well, but the Migrate portion refuses to work at random intervals, giving the error

> Establishing connection with the source database failed. External component has thrown an exception.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ...what is the exception message?

Comment: Any updates? Did you solve this issue?

Comment: I gave up on SQL Server -- using SharePoint is MUCH easier!!!!